# Make a class printable

Tags: java

When I print the instances of some classes (e.g. `ArrayList`) to a stream, e.g. `System.out.println(`*instance of ArrayList*`)`, it doesn't print the reference id (e.g. ArrayList@2144c53d), but the actual values, with some formatting (e.g. [1,2,3,4]). I was wondering how I can do this for my own classes? Do I perhaps have to define some method/implement some interface?

Comment: override toString() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try to print an object of a class using `System.out.print` , it looks for `toString()` method in that class. If it doesn't find in the given class then it tries to look up that method in its superclass untill it finds one. And then print the `String` returned by `toString()` method defined in the class. And if a class  doesn't extend anything then it by default calls the `toString` method of `Object` , which returns the String something like this:

```
public String toString() 
{
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

That's why you are getting such type of output when printing your own class object. To print different you should override `toString()` method in your own class . For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private int roll;
  private String name;
  MyClass(int roll,String name)
  {
    this.roll = roll;
    this.name = name;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "roll="+roll+",name="+name;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. I like the answer as it explains why he's getting what he's getting, rather than just giving him the solution.

Answer (score 11):

Simple: you override the [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString%28%29) method. For example:

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final LocalDate birthDate;

    public Person(String name, LocalDate birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s (born %s)", name, birthDate);
    }
}
```

For more complex handling, you might want to consider implementing the [`Formattable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formattable.html) interface - although I've never personally done so myself.

Comment: Your were the first to reply :) Thanks.

Comment: @user1377000 He is always first and fast.

Answer (score 2):

> . I was wondering how I can do this for my own classes?

By Overriding `toString()` method in your class.

```
public class MyClass {
@override
public String toString(){
return "I am a legend MwhAhAH";
}
}
```

If you don't override toStirng() in your class, `Object#toString()` will be invoked, which returns `yourclassname+ "@"+ hexnumberOfHashcode`.

```
public String toString() {
  237           return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
  238       }
```

ArrayList does override toString method:

```
  public String toString() {
431        Iterator<E> i = iterator();
432        if (! i.hasNext())
433            return "[]";
434
435        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
436        sb.append('[');
437        for (;;) {
438            E e = i.next();
439            sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
440            if (! i.hasNext())
441                return sb.append(']').toString();
442            sb.append(", ");
443        }
444    }
445
446}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override

`toString()` method.

This method is Object class which basically give output like.

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

To get anything else you need to override this in your class.

Example: ArrayList when you print arraylist the its give the arraylist elements intead of ArrayList@2144c53d

```
 public String toString() {
   return "Stackoverflow";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you should just need to override `toString()` method.

Something like the following will need to be done:

```
public class MyClass {
    @override
    public String toString(){
        return "My custom string, perhaps using some of the class propertis";
    }
}
```